# file_put_contents in head of another file using php

Tags: php, html

So, Im creating a library for other uses, but how can I make content from a file specificly go within the `<head>` or `<body>` html tag attribute etc...

for example, this is what im trying to make.

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php include('content/starter/library.php'); ?>

    <!-- From that included file, theres a script that put content in the head.-->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- From that included file, theres a script that put content in the body -->
</body>
</html>
```

Im just trying to find another way instead of making multiple files for specific sections and do

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php include('content/starter/library_head.php'); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include('content/starter/library_body.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Which I don't really want to do. Im not very good with javascript so, There no hope of me trying to figure out how to do this with javascript. Thanks for the answers in the future.

Comment: You should make the files separate, that way header and footer files, which are typically the same on every page, can be included with one line of code. But, the way you're doing it now, is the way most people do it. Except they usually include the head tags in the header file. However, this largely depends on your application as a whole, so it will be difficult for people to tell you the best thing to do here.

Comment: Also, the body wouldn't be a static file. It would need to contain variables and functions to dynamically render html. This also depends on the type of application. Because, in a lot of cases the body would just be built on each page.

Comment: Im just using 1 php file, and want certain parts of the php to be inserted into the other page that included the php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use one file (as your questions suggests) then one method is to create variables or functions in your library.php file and then echo them in your template

```
// contents of the library.php file...
<?php
    $head_content = "put your <head> content here";
    $body_content = "put your <body> content here";
?>

// your HTML file...
<?php include('content/starter/library.php'); ?>
<html>
<head>
    <?php echo $head_content ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo $body_content ?>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE

To answer the question in your comment, here's an example using a function. You can put all of your code in a function and then just echo that anywhere in your document.

```
<?php
// contents of library.php...
function head() {
    $return  = '<link href="file.css" rel="stylesheet">';
    $return .= '<link href="another_file.css" rel="stylesheet">';

    return $return;
}

// your HTML file...
<html>
<head>
    <?php echo head(); ?>
</head>
```

PHP functions explained: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_functions.asp

Comment: Is there another way to do this with using variables.

Comment: But i have 1 php file with with style and div, Is there a way to make php sections, instead of making them in "" or '', This example is still creating something like variables.

Comment: Or we can say, I want to include a certain part of a file which is php which cannot be a variable. Is it possible to make a php function with php inside? And when the function is called, it will execute the php within it?

Comment: These *are* in sections. I'm doing *exactly* what you requested in your question: one file that contains all of the content to put into your HTML page.

Comment: A PHP function does have PHP inside and will execute the code inside the function - as well as code in other functions. I suggest you read up on functions to see what they're capable of. :)

Comment: Say for example i have 1 html file and want to include it in another. I want the html, head, & body to be in the correct tag in the other file when included. So say for example I have a title in a file, i included the php file, and theres a function to see if theres a head attribute, if it does, it will put that title in the head, not just where the file was included. Without making any echos or variables that has for me to recreate the file and put them all in "", which is a waste of time. I hope you understand, I don't really speak good english.

Comment: I've pretty much showed you how to do exactly what you've been asking for without having to complicate things with functions to see if there's a head attribute. I think you're over-thinking and over-complicating things at this point. My example show you how to include one file and then put the content where you want it. It's really quite simple.

Comment: @Tim Welcome back Tim, it's been a while since we've heard about you. Hope all is well with you, *cheers*